# How to create smooth height change animation in android

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I want to create smooth animation of height change. Below, You can see my current implementation. It works, but is not smooth as I expect.

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class HeightAnimation extends Animation {
     private final int targetHeight;
     private final View view;
     private final int height;

     public HeightAnimation(View view, int targetHeight) {
         this.view = view;
         this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
         height = view.getHeight();
     }

     @Override
     protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
         view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (height + (targetHeight - height) * interpolatedTime);
         view.requestLayout();
     }

     @Override
     public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
                       int parentHeight) {
         super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean willChangeBounds() {
         return true;
     }
 }
```

Does anyone has better solution for that? Maybe there is a way to use ObjectAnimator?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a class that extends `Animation`, I think you should use `ObjectAnimator` to drive this.

```
private void animateViewHeight(View view, int targetHeight) {
    ValueAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view.getHeight(), targetHeight);

    animator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    });

    animator.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple way 
and its enough smooth

```
view.clearAnimation();
view.animate().translateY(150);
```

to roll back to previous position

```
view.clearAnimation();
view.animate().translateY(0);
```